# How to unlock AAA games?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

I just finished the game, but I didn't manage to get AAA or to make a console. I am playing it again, but I never knew how to make AAA games.

**What do you need to do to make AAA Games?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To unlock the research for AAA games, you have to develop a Large size game with a score of 10-10-10-10 or 9-10-10-10 ([source](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Research_Unlocks)).

You complete this research in the R&D lab, which requires a design specialist. You can reduce the monetary cost of research by having multiple design specialists. When you start to develop a AAA title, the research option "Marketing Campaign" is temporarily unlocked in the R&D Lab, and it will generate hype ([source](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/R&D_lab)).

If you also have a Hardware lab and are developing a AAA game, you can research hardware specific to your AAA title, which will increase either hype or sales. This acts similar to the Marketing Campaign from the R&D Lab (I can't remember or find a source).

Both the Hardware and R&D research boosts for AAA games cost 1000 research points.

Answer (score 2):

You need to train one of the employees (It can be the creator) to be a design specialist. When they finish the training the option to build the R&D lab is opened.

In the R&D lab, you can research the AAA game, also you can research "Hardware" which opens the option to build your Hardware lab, where a new Console can be created.

According to the [wiki](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/R%26D_lab), Hardware research is available as soon as the R&D lab is created, the AAA however needs some criteria to be met for it to available for research.

Comment: No, I had that lab... I had a design and tech specialist. I could only research the internet, hardware lab, and own convention.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is very late and someone probably already figured it out but here are the criterias:

1. R&D lab to research AAA games
2. Diamond (10 Million) sales of Large Game. You'll know you hit 10 mil even before the sales began cause the game will tell you you'll be able to research AAA games. Got mine with an RPG-Adventure combo.